# VBA regex regular expressions

Tags: regex, vba

I have an input string:

```
str= "row1:=dep_id=1,salary<3000;row22:=dep_id=1,salary<3000; row33:=dep_id=5,salary>5000"
```

Regex pattern:

```
regex.Pattern = "row\d+:=(.*?);"
```

Output:

```
MatchCollectionItem: row1:=dep_id=1,salary<3000;
SubMatchItem: dep_id=1,salary<3000

MatchCollectionItem: row22:=dep_id=1,salary<3000;
SubMatchItem: dep_id=1,salary<3000
```

It does not return the last ("row33...") because it ends without ";".

I've tried a few variations for the pattern

```
regex.Pattern = "row\d+:=(.*?)[;$]"
regex.Pattern = "row\d+:=(.*?)[;|$]"
```

However, the result is the same.

How to "tell" the the regex to match everything ending with ";" OR the end of string?

I need regex solution only, please.

Comment: `$` inside of a character set gets treated as a literal dollar sign, not an end line anchor. You want `(?:;|$)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern with multiline option enabled:

```
row\d+:=(.*?)(?:;|$)
```

Using square brackets, the $ gets treated as a Dollar sign.

For trying out RegEx-patterns, I use [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/).